# Is semi-concavity a local property?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

The usual definition of semiconcave for a function $f$ defined on an open set $\Omega$ is, if for any $x\in \Omega,h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x,x-h,x+h\in \Omega$ then
$$ f(x-h)-2f(x) + f(x+h) \leq c|h|^2$$
for some $c>0$.

My question is, would it be enough to have $$ f(x-h)-2f(x) + f(x+h) \leq c|h|^2$$ for all $|h|\ll 1$ small enough and still have $f$ is semiconcave?

Comment: If $f$ is twice cont. differentiable then it would satisfy the second condition always (choose $c=\max_{|h|\le1} |f''(x+h)|)$.

Comment: So on bounded set the two conditions should be correct!